# Trouble with grouping by and counting in r

Tags: r

I have a data.frame called world. This data frame lists countries in column name.y, I have a column for languages named languages.  I need to List the names of countries where more than 4 languages are spoken.

My first take on this is to aggregate country and languages.

```
language <- data.frame(table(World$name.y,World$language))
```

when I run head(language) it doesn't work out.

Comment: `library(data.table); as.data.table(World)[, .(n=length(unique(language))),by=.(country)][n>=4,]`

Comment: Sorry, but there was an error with this one. `Error in `[.data.table`(as.data.table(World), , .(n = length(unique(language))),  : 
  column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type list. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]`

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` package should be useful for this.

```
library(dplyr)

World %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(num_distinct_languages = n_distinct(language)) %>%
  filter(num_distinct_lanagues > 4)
```